# IIS 7.5 points to wrong physical path

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, https, iis-7.5

We have a requirement to create two websites(let's call them Website_A and Website_B) on IIS, with two different IP addresses. There is only one SSL certificate to be bound to both the websites.

I have successfully created Website_A, with the web application's physical path as `D:/IIS/Folder_A/Application_A`. I have bound this website to an SSL certificate and an IP address. It works fine.

The issue occurs with the second website, Website_B; I have created this website with the web application's physical path configured as follows:
`D:/IIS/Folder_B/Application_B`. 
I have bound Website_B to the same SSL certificate as Website_A, but with a different IP address.

When I try to run Website_B in the web browser, it throws the following error:

```
**404 NOT FOUND: 
The resource you are looking has been removed, or has its name changed
Physical path : D:/IIS/Folder_A/Application_B**
```

This is what is strange: I have configured Website_B's application physical path as Folder_B--> Application_B

But, the error shows that IIS is looking for the application in the wrong path, it is searching in Folder_A(belonging to Website_A) , instead of Folder_B.

I have restarted IIS and rechecked the physical paths in IIS, but the problem persists.

All I can understand is, Website_B is using some old configuration belonging to the Website_A, maybe from a cache location which is not refreshed. But I am not sure exactly where.

I did find a few questions on this issue on Stack Overflow, but they are either unanswered or didn't have helpful answers.

Comment: Separate application pools?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have created separate application pools for each website